# AngularJS: How to check if value exists in array of objects?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object, indexof

I'm trying to write a function that iterates through an array of objects, and pushes in new ones (ones that have a unique name), while updating ones that have already been seen.

Say for example, I have this array:

```
$scope.myArray = [
    { "name": "Apple", "total": 16, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Cherry", "total": 12, "applicable": 27 },
    { "name": "Plum", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Apple", "total": 16, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Cherry", "total": 12, "applicable": 27 },
    { "name": "Plum", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Banana", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
];
```

By the end of the function, the new array should be:

```
$scope.myNewArray = [
    { "name": "Apple", "total": 32, "applicable": 42},
    { "name": "Cherry", "total": 24, "applicable": 54},
    { "name": "Plum", "total": 28, "applicable": 42},
    { "name": "Banana", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
];
```

**Here's what I have so far:**

```
$scope.myArray = [
    { "name": "Apple", "total": 16, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Cherry", "total": 12, "applicable": 27 },
    { "name": "Plum", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Apple", "total": 16, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Cherry", "total": 12, "applicable": 27 },
    { "name": "Plum", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Banana", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
];

$scope.myNewArray = [];

$scope.myArray.filter( function () {

    var i = $scope.myNewArray.indexOf($scope.myArray.name);

    if ($scope.myNewArray.indexOf($scope.myArray.name) < 0)
        $scope.myNewArray.push($scope.myArray);

    else {
        $scope.myNewArray[i].total += $scope.myArray.total;
        $scope.myNewArray[i].applicable += $scope.myArray.applicable;
    }
});
```

The problem I'm encountering is everything gets pushed into the new array. That and I believe my else statement where I'm adding the values to the previous record might be wrong.

Also, hard-coding an array for each name doesn't work as this is just a simple example with a small dataset.

Can anyone lend a hand?

Comment: What I do to simply such things is I use angular forEach and in your case, I'd make three different arrays and fill them up with this information. Then I'd use indexof on them and push them to myNewArray. Its easier to work on simple arrays than array objects.

Comment: @ThatBird wish I could do that, unfortunately, this is just a simple version of what I'm trying to accomplish. So with this example, three arrays would work, but with a bigger data set, it would not. Plus, with your suggested approach, this wouldn't be dynamic. but rather hardcoded

Comment: Well, I've worked on some 50 thousand values(mostly more than this) with this method and I never ran into any trouble. Although yes, you'd have to know beforehand what you're going to recieve in your data object(myArray in your case)

Comment: @thatbird, you're right :) might have to go with this solution

Comment: I'll post this as an answer too, let me know if you run into some trouble !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this approach:

1. create object where keys are *name* property and *total* along with *applicable* are already calculated (`Array.prototype.reduce`)
2. Iterate over keys of previously created object and transform it back to array (`Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.map`)

```js
var res = {};
res = Object.keys([
    { "name": "Apple", "total": 16, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Cherry", "total": 12, "applicable": 27 },
    { "name": "Plum", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Apple", "total": 16, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Cherry", "total": 12, "applicable": 27 },
    { "name": "Plum", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
    { "name": "Banana", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
].reduce(function (res, item) {
  if (res[item.name]) {
    res[item.name].total += item.total;
    res[item.name].applicable += item.applicable;
  }
  else {
    res[item.name] = item;
  }
  return res; 
}, res)).map(function(key) {
  return res[key];
});
console.log(res);
```

adding less hardcoded solution:

```js
var myArray = [
  { "name": "Apple", "total": 16, "applicable": 21 },
  { "name": "Cherry", "total": 12, "applicable": 27 },
  { "name": "Plum", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
  { "name": "Apple", "total": 16, "applicable": 21 },
  { "name": "Cherry", "total": 12, "applicable": 27 },
  { "name": "Plum", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
  { "name": "Banana", "total": 14, "applicable": 21 },
];

var res = {};
  
// add keys for loopable integers which will be summed   
var loopables = Object.keys(myArray[0]).filter(function (key) {
  return Number.isInteger(myArray[0][key]);
});

res = Object.keys(myArray.reduce(function (res, item) {
  if (res[item.name]) {
    loopables.forEach(function (loopableKey) {
      res[item.name][loopableKey] += item[loopableKey];
    });
    
  }
  else {
    res[item.name] = item;
  }
  return res; 
}, res)).map(function(key) {
  return res[key];
});
console.log(res);
```

here I only rely on the main key *name*, the rest integer properties are automatically summed, by iterating over *loopables* keys array, calculated at the beginning

plunker with Angular: https://plnkr.co/edit/MRr2QRULG8TYs2CqA1By?p=preview

Comment: This is badass, but can you explain how the above code would work if the array of objects was not explicitly stated? Meaning, instead of the array being hard-coded out, it's already set as a variable? say for example, `$scope.myArray`. I ask because you have the `reduce` function mid array declaration.

Comment: updated my answer with another snippet, where array is in the variable, and summed values are calculated programmatically

Answer (score 1):

What I do to simply such things is I use angular forEach and in your case, I'd make three different arrays and fill them up with this information. Then I'd use indexof on them and push them to myNewArray. Its easier to work on simple arrays than array objects.

For example on forEach [Angular forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it in pure javascript

check this following snippet

```js
  var obj = [{
            "name": "Apple",
            "total": 16,
            "applicable": 21
}, {
            "name": "Cherry",
            "total": 12,
            "applicable": 27
}, {
            "name": "Plum",
            "total": 14,
            "applicable": 21
}, {
            "name": "Apple",
            "total": 16,
            "applicable": 21
}, {
            "name": "Cherry",
            "total": 12,
            "applicable": 27
}, {
            "name": "Plum",
            "total": 14,
            "applicable": 21
}, {
            "name": "Banana",
            "total": 14,
            "applicable": 21
}, ];

        var newObj = [];

        MergeObjectProperties(obj);

        function MergeObjectProperties(obj) {
            Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
                var name = obj[key].name;
                var exists = checkProperty(name, newObj)
                if (newObj.length == 0 || !exists)
                    newObj.push(obj[key]);
                else {
                    newObj[exists]["total"] = obj[key].total + newObj[exists]["total"];
                    newObj[exists]["applicable"] = obj[key].applicable + newObj[exists]["applicable"];
                }
            });
         console.log(newObj);
        }

        function checkProperty(prop, newObj) {
            var result;
            Object.keys(newObj).forEach(function (key) {
                if (newObj[key]["name"] === prop) {
                    result = key
                }
            });
            return result;
        }
```

Hope this helps